# How to limit number of post per user WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a listing site using WordPress, I want to limit each user to one post. Is there a code I can use to limit the number of post of a particular "post-type" in wordpress?

Comment: To clarify, I want users to only be able to publish one post.

Comment: when a user can  publish post, after login or without login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Limit Post" plugin to achieve this. It is exactly providing features which you are looking for. 
Here you can find the plugin:

`https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-posts`

You can also check "Bainternet Posts Creation Limits" plugin here:

`https://wordpress.org/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits`